# Make hint to use in another chapter

Tags: macros, environments, exam

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[solution]{print=true}

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
         This is a question
        
    \end{question}

    \begin{solution}
    This is an answer       
    \end{solution}  

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to beside the solution environment, I have a hint for each question such that those hint printed according to 'chapter number.question number' in the chapter Hints. How it could possible to define such a command or environment? Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{hint}{%
    \def\@currentlabel{\BODY}\label{hint:\thequestion}%
    
    
    
}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\printmyhints{%
    
    
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thequestion}{% 
        
        \noindent
        \thechapter.\x.~\ref{hint:\x}\par
    }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation?
        
    \end{question}
    \begin{hint}
        a hint is here!
    \end{hint}
    \begin{solution}
        this is a solution
    \end{solution}
    \chapter{answer Sheet}

        \printmyhints
    

\end{document}
```

The problem of above code is hints must has counter 1.1,1.2 but those get started from chapter 2.

Comment: You can check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673420/collecting-hints-to-exercises-with-xsim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to store the chapter and question number with the hint and to use a separate counter for the hints (labels).

I also gratuitously replaced `\foreach` with a TeX `\loop`.  Just remember to loop over the hint counter.

BTW, this qualifies as the aux file approach.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{hint}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{hint}{\refstepcounter{hint}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\thequestion~\BODY}%
    \label{hint:\thehint}%
}
\newcommand\printmyhints{% you could use \foreach, but this is faster
\bgroup% use local registers
  \count1=\value{hint}% a macro would also work
  \setcounter{hint}{0}%
  \loop\ifnum\value{hint}<\count1
    \stepcounter{hint}%
    \noindent\ref{hint:\thehint}\par
  \repeat
\egroup}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation?
        
    \end{question}
    \begin{hint}
        a hint is here!
    \end{hint}
    \begin{solution}
        this is a solution
    \end{solution}
    \chapter{answer Sheet}

        \printmyhints
    

\end{document}
```

---

This shows a savebox approach.  In order to allow multiline text, it uses `\vbox` instead of `\hbox` style saveboxes.  `udbox` is a `\vbox` version of `lrbox`.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\def\udbox#1{% fragile
  \edef\reserved@a{%
  \endgroup
  \setbox#1\vbox{%
  \begingroup\aftergroup}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
  \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
  \@endpefalse
  \color@setgroup
  \ignorespaces}
\def\endudbox{\unskip\color@endgroup}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\hintbox}

\newenvironment{hint}{\begin{udbox}{\hintbox}%
  \unvbox\hintbox
  \noindent\thechapter.\thequestion\space}%
{\end{udbox}%
  \global\setbox\hintbox=\copy\hintbox}

\newcommand\printmyhints{\usebox\hintbox}


\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        Which of the following answers is correct for the given recurrence relation?
        
    \end{question}
    \begin{hint}
      Consider the following:
      %\hrule
      \begin{itemize}
        \item test
      \end{itemize}
    \end{hint}
    \begin{solution}
        this is a solution
    \end{solution}
    \chapter{answer Sheet}

        \printmyhints

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you look at this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700511/generating-bubble-answer-sheet

Comment: If I put for example some \item in the Hint environment, it doesn't work. How is it possible to resolve this?

Comment: Occasionally , I must write an itemize environment in hint environment but I get error. How I can resolve this? Thanks

Comment: I use environment solution for other purpose, so I shouldn't use that to print bubble in that. From this argument I decide to introduce environment correctchoice, Could you according to this observation modify correctchoice to accept \buuble command? Thank you

Comment: The problem seems to occur in the `\edef` stage.  `\protected@edef` doesn't help.  This may be inherent in the environ \BODY approach.